# Unusual sturucture: What does it mean "which to"?

Tags: relative-clauses, subordinate-clauses

I have a question that confuses my mind. I've come across this text:

> "You have eight hours in **which to** complete this exam."

The point which I didn't understand is the meaning of "which to ...". Because "which" is a relative clause. And relative clauses contain subject and verb. Here is the definition of clause:

> A clause “a group of words containing a subject and predicate and
> functioning as a member of a complex or compound sentence" (Merriam-Webster).

Okay so, normally after relative words there should be a clause which includes subject and verb like in this example: "This is the stone against which **he leaned**." But in mine, interestingly there is no complete clause. There is just an infinitive verb.

Could you please explain the reason why there is not a complete sentence after "which"?

**Edit**: To make myself more clear I changed and shorten the question.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I think OP is confused why the part after "against which" sometimes has a subject and sometimes not. "In which **X can Y**" vs. "In which **to Y**."

Comment: Thank yo for answer Michael. I actually know this. But, it should have be "a standard against which measure" without "to".

Comment: My friends thank you for your responses. Neither "why there is not subject" nor why "there is against before which" is my question. My question is why there is "to" before the verb which is "measure"? More clearly why the verb is in the form of the infinitive?

Comment: Because that's the way English works! We could say instead "against which one can measure..."  "in which you must complete..."  "on which you/we/one can build...

Comment: Thank you Bill. Why the verb is in infinitive form. I mean normally after relative clause there should be a sencence. For example it should have been sad "You have eight hourse in which you copmlete this exam"  instead of "You have eight hours in which to complete this exam".

Comment: The reason that I don't understand is infinitive form of a verb is not a sentence. But after relatives there should be sentences. Like in these examples:
- Did your son like the present which you bought him for his birthday? 
- I’ve repaired the chair whic was broken yesterday. 

But in mine, there is not a complete sentence. I hope, I made myself clear

Comment: You've changed the examples in your question (which you shouldn't do) so I've deleted my previous comment as it is no longer relevant.

Comment: Sorry, BillJ. I had to change. Because using past examples I couldn't explain my question. I was just wondering the reason for coming to the verb as an infinitive.

Comment: It's a form of purpose clause.

Comment: Relative clauses are subordinate so they are not (normally) complete sentences. There's nothing unusual about an infinitival relative clause like _in which to complete this exam_. The relative clause can be paraphrased as "to complete this exam in eight hours"

Comment: Infinitival relatives typically have a modal meaning compatible to that expressed in finites by _can_ or _should_. Compare _You have eight hours in which you should complete this exam_.

Comment: Oh gosh! I can understand it now! I didn't know this kind of usage of infinitival relatives. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *You have eight hours* [*in which to complete this exam*].

The bracketed element is an infinitival relative clause where "which” has "eight hours" as antecedent.

The relative clause is understood as "to complete the exam in eight hours", where the PP "in eight hours" is a temporal adjunct within the relative clause.

Infinitival relatives typically have a modal meaning comparable to that expressed in finites by "can" or "should". Compare *You have eight hours in which you should complete this exam.*

Answer (score 0):

This is an ellipsis. The command

> Those of you who are taking this exam have eight hours in which you are required to complete this exam

is exact but verbose and gets abbreviated to

> You have eight hours in which to complete this exam

The missing words “those of,” “who are taking this exam,” and “you are required to” are implicitly communicated by context.

Of course the result is still verbose.

> Complete this exam in eight hours

Comment: There's no ellipsis. "in which to complete this exam" is an infinitival relative clause, with a modal meaning similar to "in which you should complete this exam".

Comment: Thanks for answer Jeff. But I agree with BillJ. Because after a little researching, I think there is no this kind of ellipsis in grammar. You can check this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics)